# Can ajax:success .on() be bound to a class selector?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

My success callback is not firing when I bind it to a class selector.

Instance of the class:

```
<div id="entries">
  ...
  <a href="/entries/user_tag_search?search=Fly+Tying" class="entry-ajax-tag-search" data-remote="true">Fly Tying</a>
  ...
</div>
```

Callback definition:

```
  $(function(){
    $("#entries").on("ajax:success", ".entry-ajax-tag-search", function(){
      $(".entries-accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: 'content', event: "click keyup" });
    })
  })
```

Where `#entries` content is replaced dynamically by the remote ajax call.

My understanding of `.on` was that it would capture the `ajax:success` from the contained elements and as #entries` is static (available on initial page load and never rewritten) the binding would persist.

I can fallback to `.bind`, but I'd like to know why this doesn't work before I do.

I don't know if it's relevant, but the callback does show-up on the link in the chrome debugger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Is this the plugin you're using](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)

Comment: Yes, I'm using jquery_ujs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work, I believe it's an issue with `jquery_ujs` but I haven't dug into it.

My work around is to place the `js` that I want executed in the `.on()` handler into a `<script> </script>` section of the html returned by the view:

```
<div id="entries-accordion-for-subscription-<%= @current_subscription_id %>" class="accordion entries-accordion">
  <%= render @entries %>
</div>
<script>
  /* MAGICAL!!!!! DO NOT TOUCH!!!!!!!
     This *usually* works, although it appears to be DOM loading sensitive once in a while. */
    $(".entries-accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: 'content', event: "click keyup" });
</script>
```

Not pretty but it gets the job done for now.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, "#entries" is never dynamically replaced but `on` wasn't binding my elements. The solution I found (without using `bind`) was to attach `on` to `document`

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#entries .entry-ajax-tag-search", function(){
  ...
})
```

Comment: Not firing on this either, I'll double-check to make sure that #entries isn't being replaced someplace. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have the same mystery with a `$('select#blah').on('change', ...)` ... Did you solve it on your side?